# How can I choose which column do I refer to?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join

I have 2 tables with some duplicate columns. I need to join them **without picking which columns I want to select**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS animals (
  id int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  cond varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  animal varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO animals (id, cond, animal) VALUES
  ('1', 'fat', 'cat'),
  ('2', 'slim', 'cat'),
  ('3', 'fat', 'dog'),
  ('4', 'slim', 'dog'),
  ('5', 'normal', 'dog');
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names (
  id int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  animal varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO names (id, name, animal) VALUES
  ('1', 'LuLu', 'cat'),
  ('2', 'DoDo', 'cat'),
  ('3', 'Jack', 'dog'),
  ('4', 'Shorty', 'dog'),
  ('5', 'Stinky', 'dog');

SELECT *
FROM animals AS a
JOIN names as n
ON a.id = n.id;
```

Result:

```
| id  | cond   | animal | id  | name   | animal |
| --- | ------ | ------ | --- | ------ | ------ |
| 1   | fat    | cat    | 1   | LuLu   | cat    |
| 2   | slim   | cat    | 2   | DoDo   | cat    |
| 3   | fat    | dog    | 3   | Jack   | dog    |
| 4   | slim   | dog    | 4   | Shorty | dog    |
| 5   | normal | dog    | 5   | Stinky | dog    |
```

But when I try to make another request from the resulting table like:

```
SELECT name
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM animals AS a
JOIN names as n
ON a.id = n.id
) as res_tbl
WHERE name = 'LuLu';
```

I get:

> Query Error: Error: ER_DUP_FIELDNAME: Duplicate column name 'id'

Is there any way of avoiding it except removing duplicate columns from the 1st request?

P.S. in fact I am using PostgreSQL, I create my schema as MySQL because I am more used to it

Comment: Please show us the result you want, as tabular text.

Comment: Wait, is it Postgresql or MySQL that raises the exception?

Comment: I just want to make requests from the resulting table of the 1st request without removing duplicate columns or changing it in general. Nothing particular. Let's say pick a record where name = 'LuLu'

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh , I use both of them. In PostgeSQL I have a following problem: when I try to use smth like
SELECT animal
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM animals AS a
JOIN names as n
ON a.id = n.id
) as res_tbl
WHERE animal = 'cat'; 
I get: column reference "animal" is ambiguous

Comment: First, the `CREATE TABLE` DDL will as posted above will not work on Postgres, no `unsigned`, DEFAULT. Second, when I converted them to Postgres style I could not replicate error. Third, what does `SELECT n.*` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have columns with the same name in both tables, which causes ambiguity.

If you just want the `name` column in the outer query, then `select` that column only in the subquery:

```
select name
from (
    select n.name
    from animals a
    inner join names n using (id)
) t
where ...
```

If you want more columns, then you would typically alias the homonym columns to remove the ambiguity - as for the joining column (here, `id`), the `using()` syntax is sufficient. So, for example:

```
select ...
from (
    select id, a.cond, a.animal as animal1, n.name, n.animal as animal2
    from animals a
    inner join names n using (id)
) t
where ...
```

You may also select the records themselves, instead of the columns from them, which you can then access in an outer query using the usual record.column syntax;

```
SELECT a.cond animal_cond,
       n.name animal_name
FROM (
SELECT a, n
FROM animals AS a
JOIN names as n
ON a.id = n.id
) t
```